# NoClassDefFoundError in Eclipse at Runtime when downloading dependency via Gradle (but works when using Jar file)

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, maven-central

I have a build.gradle with some dependencies. One of the dependencies is Apache commons-logging

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2'
}
```

I use mavenCrentral to resolve most of the dependencies. Some libs however are saved as jar files in a directory on my file system. I tell gradle where to find these libs:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs "${rootProject.projectDir}/libs"
    }
}
```

When I put the commons-logging-1.2.jar in the libs folder, such that I can see this path for the jar in my "Project and External Dependencies" in Eclipse, then everything works fine.

However, when I remove this jar from the libs folder, such that gradle downloads it from mavenCentral and stores it in ".../.gradle/caches/...", then I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
```

when running the project.

The jar downloaded by gradle from maven central and the one that I have in my local lib folder are identical (they have the same MD5 checksum).
In Eclipse I can see the jar file under "Project and External Dependencies" in both cases. Thus the jar seems to be on the classpath. Only difference is the path of the jar file. It is either ".../my-project/libs/..." or ".../.gradle/caches/...".

Why are these dependencies not equivalent? Is it an issue with Eclipse or Gradle or my setup?

Comment: Are you using the gradle eclipse plugin? Did you recreate the eclipse project and classpath files after changing your gradle file?

Comment: Yes I use the eclipse plugin and Buildship. After changing the build.gradle, I do "Right Click on Project" > "Gradle" > "Refresh Gradle Project"

Comment: Don't rely on the buildship plugin - I know some people will hate me for this. Maybe you could try to run `gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse` from the command line and see if this produces a different result.

Comment: Just tried this. It does not make a difference.

Comment: Ok, when only changing the lib of commons-logging, then it seems to work. However, when I switch all my libs to use maven-central, I get the above error.
It is still weird though.

Comment: You could try to check your application's classpath on runtime `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` and see if there is something unexpected.